# how to insert modulus and exponent of RSA public key into FGInt package(http://submanifold.be/)

Tags: delphi, rsa, public-key

I'm newby in RSA cryptographic methods... I need to verify incoming signature from device. The problem is, that I have to use a delphi IDE and delhi doesn't have implemented some RSA libraries. I find on web the FGInt package on this site: http://submanifold.be/. I download it(RSA.zip) and I'm in dark - I don't know, how can I put to this code my public key modulus and exponent.

The situation is as follows:
I have signature from device which I need to compare(verify) with calculated message(challenge). I have also an X509 certificate  with embedded public key. I can extract this public key from these certificate. I can also extract modulus and exponent from public key. My problem is, that I don't know, how can I put the obtained modulus and exponent to RSAVerify procedure of FGInt package. The modulus is 128 bytes(I have it as an array of hexa numbers) long and exponent has value of 65537.

Can somebody help with my question, how can be modulus and exponent values inserted into procedure RSAVerify in FGint package?

Answer (score 3):

If you need RSA functions and you're running on Windows, use the MSCRYPTO API. Info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_CryptoAPI and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380255(v=vs.85).aspx

If you intend to make your application available outside the US, incorporating custom or third party encryption logic into your application will make your app fall into the "software munitions" category of US export restrictions. You will have to apply for an export permit, have your code reviewed by US government reps, etc. or risk hefty fines and possibly criminal charges for export violations.

If your app instead links to the MSCRYPTO library, you don't have to do any of that. Microsoft takes care of getting export permits for the MSCRYPTO library shipped with Windows.